# What is wrong in my amazon autoscalling?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have an EC2 instance that I want to scale based on the number of messages in a SQS queue. If there are many messages (for 5 minutes) I want to pop up a new EC2, for consuming faster the messages. Then if the messages are few (for 5 minutes), I want to pop down the oldest EC2. This way, if the service that consumes the messages stops for some reason, I will terminate the old EC2, and the service will run.

I have created an `AutoScalling` for this. I have set the `TerminationPolicy` to `OldestInstance`, but it works as I expect only if I set just one zone (eg: `eu-west-1a`): it creates a new instance and terminates the oldest each time. But if I have 3 regions (`eu-west-1a, eu-west-1b, eu-west-1c`), it just launches and terminates the instances not in the `OldestInstance` manner. Or, at least, not as I expect: delete the oldest every time. Is there something linked to different zones? On [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html#custom-termination-policy) pace I have not found anything about it, except for the default policy.

And even if the case linking to multiple zones from default policy is applied, I can have maximum only 2 instances that turn at the same time. And they are always launched in a new zone.

Comment: Like "How to write a good question?"; yes, there is *something that i do not know*

Comment: you could help me write it well, by asking what you do not understand ...

Comment: BACKGROUND INFO. Literally, your first 'sentence' is: "I have Autoscalling". To **anybody** reading this, they're not going to understand what you're on about. (and that's only the first 4 words, not the rest). Remember, noone can 'see' what the issue is without you **explaining** the issue first clearly to them. We're programmers, not mind readers.

Comment: is it better now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the key paragraph:

> When you customize the termination policy, Auto Scaling first assesses the Availability Zones for any imbalance. If an Availability Zone has more instances than the other Availability Zones that are used by the group, then Auto Scaling applies your specified termination policy on the instances from the imbalanced Availability Zone. **If the Availability Zones used by the group are balanced, then Auto Scaling selects an Availability Zone at random** and applies the termination policy that you specified.

I interpret this to mean that if you have instances in multiple zones, and those zones are already balanced, then AWS will select a zone at random AND THEN pick the oldest instance, within the randomly selected zone - it won't pick the oldest instances across AZ's, it picks and random AZ and then the oldest instance is terminated within that AZ.

[image]

Comment: So if I want to terminate the oldest one, I have to use only one zone (a, b or c)?

Comment: I believe so yes - but then you give up a bit of cross-zone redundancy, so you ned to decide which is more important.

Comment: Can you also give the link, please?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html

Comment: Ok, the picture is more for default case, but I think it will fits for the customization too. I did not figure it out...